# Smooth mouse movement in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I was wondering if anyone could help me with some code, essentially I've made a small function that moves the mouse cursor relative to the mouse cursor's current position, however the cursor teleports; I'd like to find a way to make it 'glide', smoothly so it looks a little more natural.

Here is the code below:

```
#import <Windows.h>

void MouseXY(int x, int y) {
        POINT p;
        if (GetCursorPos(&p)) {
            SetCursorPos(p.x + x, p.y + y);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you want is a "tween" or "easing function".

Comment: Use some kind of timer and update the cursor position in steps. Whether this is a WM_TIMER message (or timer callback), or an animation effect from the animation manager is up to you.

Comment: Interesting... why you need a function like this

Comment: Because I've developed a program that moves the mouse, however it looks robotic and I'd like to make it feel more natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the cursor to slide smoothly instead of teleporting, I would suggest using while loop, some delta value, and Sleep function...

What you are basically doing there is instantaneously moving the cursor.

What you probably want is to move the cursor with smaller steps.